# Bayesian Estimator and Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This is Exercise 6.1.14 from Dembo's notes found [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310a/lnotes.pdf).  At this point, we are just beginning a discussion of Markov chains.  I have no prior experience with estimators and so I am a bit lost with this problem.  The problem is as follows:

Let $\theta$ and $(U_k)_k$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.  Let $X_k = sgn(\theta - U_k)$ and $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.

(a) Compute $\mathbb{P} [ X_{n+1} = 1 \mid X_1, \ldots, X_n]$

(b) Show that $(S_n)_n$ is a Markov chain.  Is it homogeneous?

I am having trouble with part (a) (I'm guessing part (b) will be not so difficult given part (a), but I could be wrong).

I thought I had a semi-sensible attempt at a solution, but while writing it out here, I realized it actually doesn't make sense. So I am know back at square 1, and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To map part (a) to the question linked to, note that the order of $\theta$ and the $U_k$ up to $U_{n+1}$ is a random permutation of $n+2$ objects, the given condition is that $\theta$ is greater than all $U_k$ up to $U_n$, and you want to know the probability that it is also greater than $U_{n+1}$, i.e., that it is the greatest of the $n+2$ values.

Comment: The above comment refers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366571).

Comment: @joriki Thanks, I will think about that.

Comment: @joriki: You seem to be assuming all the $X_1,\ldots , X_n$ are $+1$.  I am not sure the question implies that.  Instead, see the $S_n$ as a random walk of sorts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints for (a):

- With $\theta$ having any distribution on $(0,1)$ and $U_{n+1}$ independently uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, you have $\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=1]=\mathbb{P}[U_{n+1} \lt \theta]=\mathbb{E}[\theta]$
- You can find the posterior distribution for $\theta$ in the usual way: the prior density for $\theta$ multiplied by the likelihood of the observed data, divided by the integral over $\theta$ to give a probability density ...
- ... and so you can find the posterior expectation of $\theta$

Comment: So is the conditional probability I am looking for then $\mathbb{E}[\theta \mid X_1, \ldots, X_n]$?  As I have never done anything with estimators before, I am just trying to follow this page: http://www.randomservices.org/random/point/Bayes.html  .  So in this case, (looking under the Rample sample paragraph) is 
$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \theta ) = \theta^j(1-\theta)^{n-j}$ where $j$ is the number of $1$'s in $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$?  Actually, now rethinking stuff, the work I had previously was calculating $f(x)$ in the notation on that page, and I always got $1/2$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: You should get $\dfrac{(n+1)!}{j!\, (n-j)!} \theta^j(1-\theta)^{n-j}$ as the posterior distribution for $\theta$ (a Beta distribution) and $\dfrac{j+1}{n+2}$ for the conditional probability (Laplace's rule of succession)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the help. Could you explain why it's $(n+1)!$ in the fraction instead of $n!$? (I'm guessing the factor comes from the different ways we can get $j$ ones)

Comment: Thanks, I think i figured out with your hints and comments, you can ignore the previous comment.